# Gitversion: difference between Continous Delivery/Deployment mode

Tags: git, gitversion

From reading their docs: https://gitversion.net/docs/reference/versioning-modes/

I still can't figure out what the difference is between the two.
They both seem to use prerelease tags, which I thought, was only typical for `Continuous Deployment` mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main difference is how it affects the version number deployed:

- with [Continuous Delivery](https://gitversion.net/docs/reference/versioning-modes/continuous-delivery#how-continuous-delivery-affects-gitversion), GitVersion will build the **same semantic version** until that version is deployed. The version to deploy is known.
- with [Continuous Deployment](https://gitversion.net/docs/more-info/incrementing-per-commit), GitVersion will increment the pre-release tag on every commit, as described in the "[Hijacking the pre-release tag](https://www.xavierdecoster.com/post/2013/04/29/semantic-versioning-auto-incremented-nuget-package-versions.html)" section.
  The version to deploy is unknown.
  That is why this mode is reserved for the `develop` branch only, meaning for the "`vNext`" (the "next" version, which could be a patch, minor or major one).
  That allows to auto-increment a build stamp (part of the version number)… on a yet unknown semantic version.